# Yielding processor time

Tags: ios, scheduling

I have a GUI thread and a computation thread. Because of limited resources the computation thread sometime makes the GUI thread stuck and starves it from CPU time. I the exact position in the computation thread that happens and its in a tight loop. If I could yield processing time few times in the loop the GUI thread won't be stuck.
How can I yield control in iOS? or maybe create a thread in low priority?
Right now I create the new thread like this:

```
NSOperationQueue *Queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSInvocationOperation *Operation =
    [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(loadLevel)
                                           object:nil];

[Queue addOperation: Operation];
```

Answer (score 0):

sleep(0) is a common posix trick to yield the CPU to another thread; however, are you sure you have two threads?  This isn't really common to iOS.